# How to work RTSP in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ffmpeg, rtsp

I need to catch RTSP stream from my IP-camera for convert and streaming to site. First I wanted use ffmpeg, but have not found ffmpeg wrappers for python2.7.
Who can help me?

Answer (score 4):

you don't need wrappers for ffmpeg, you can just execute commands directly from python

```
import os
os.system("ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.100/stream -codec copy -f h264 output.mp4 -codec copy -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:3000 &")
```

this captures an rtsp stream from 192.168.1.100/stream (replace this with your camera IP and streaming url, this would be in the camera settings probably on the camera site at 192.168.1.100), outputs it to an mp4 file and re-streams it to a local udp port 3000

need more information to know exactly what you're looking for

Comment: I need to take frame by frame to numpy array form from rtsp link (real time processing), any solution?

Comment: any solution with this?

Comment: Yeah but for that you need ffmpeg pre installed

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to capture a single frame from an RTSP stream and save it to disk. You could modify this to save a video stream as well if you wanted:

```
import ffmpeg

stream = ffmpeg.input("rtsp://<IP or host>:554/", ss=0)
file = stream.output("test.png", vframes=1)
testfile = file.run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
```

Comment: Maybe because it's 2021, but I had to install `ffmpeg-python` or I got the error `module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'input'`